# around command in overpass turbo not working

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I want to create a google currentplace type api using open street map data. I have been trying to use othe around command in overpass ql but it always returns error or 0,0.

```
[out:json];
(
  node["amenity"];
  >;
  (
    around(latitude=latitude,longitude=longitude,radius=100);
  );
);
out body;
```

This is the code I have been using. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax, it should be like this:

```
[out:json];
(
  node["amenity"](around:500, 53.866444, 10.684738);
);
out body;
```

This is the result:

[image]